Unable to push image to ACR from terraform - could not get auth config (the credentialhelper did not work or was not found):
I have a terraform project that creates an ACR registry, I am also using a Docker provider to build a node project locally, then push it to the ACR.
After running terraform init and trying to apply the changes, I get this error:
 Error: Error loading registry auth config: could not get auth config (the credentialhelper did not work or was not found): error getting credentials - err: no credentials server URL, out: `no credentials server URL`       
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
│   on providers.tf line 29, in provider "docker":
│   29: provider "docker" {

This is my current code

resource "random_string" "random" {
  length  = 8
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

locals {
  acr_name = "acr${random_string.random.result}"
}

module "resource_group" {
  source = "..//..//modules/resource_group"
  name_prefix = var.resource_group_name_prefix
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name = local.acr_name
  location         = module.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  sku = "Premium"
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.name
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
} 

resource "docker_image" "image" {
  name = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/my-app:v1"
  build {
    context = "./node-hello-world"
  }

}

resource "docker_registry_image" "helloworld" {
  name          = docker_image.image.name
  keep_remotely = true
}

I am using this Docker provider
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~>3.0.2"
    }

and have my auth information
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server
    username = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username
    password = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password
  }
}

Does anyone know why this is happening please?

Would you try using the admin_enabled = true property in the azurerm_container_registry resource @nearprinciple

@VinayB I tried that, still the same issue. I have docker desktop running locally, it was getting built before on my machine, for some reason now it errors out and I have no idea why.
I removed all my state and tried again but nothing, my docker/config.json looks like this, don't know what it should contain
{
"auths": {
"https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
},
"credsStore": "wincred"
}

 Error: Error loading registry auth config: could not get auth config (the credentialhelper did not work or was not found): error getting credentials - err: no credentials server URL, out: `no credentials server URL`

The above error is caused because the ACR login server details are not being retrieved from the ACR registry correctly. You can use the code below to get the ACR login server in the Docker provider.
    provider "docker" {
      registry_auth {
        address  = "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}.azurecr.io"
        username = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username
        password = azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password
      }
    }

If you are facing any errors with the Docker provider, you can use an alternative method to push the image to ACR using Terraform.
Here is the updated Terraform code to push the image to ACR

Note: In my case, I used a public image for testing, as I don't have a custom image

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "89a9"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.14.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name_prefix}-rg"
  location = var.resource_group_location
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                     = "venkatfacrtest"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                       = "Premium"
  admin_enabled            = true
  depends_on               = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}


resource "docker_image" "nginx_image" {
  name = "nginx:latest"
  depends_on = [azurerm_container_registry.acr]
}

resource "null_resource" "dockerpush" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az acr login --name ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}
      docker tag ${docker_image.nginx_image.image_id} ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}.azurecr.io/demoimage/nginx:v3 | tr -d '\r'
      docker push ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}.azurecr.io/demoimage/nginx:v3 | tr -d '\r'
    EOT
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }

  depends_on = [docker_image.nginx_image, azurerm_container_registry.acr]
}

terraform apply

After running the code, the Docker image, along with the tag, was changed and pushed to ACR successfully

ACR result


Thanks, it seemed to work after I started up docker desktop for the first time today alone with your change to not use the value from the data source.
I then destroyed the ACR and tried to recreate it, then I got the exact same error again lol.
I am probably going to just try the null_resource approach because the current one seems to be inconsistent.

The null_resource works thank you, I just had to add another | tr -d '\r' at the end of the az login command since it wasn't being escaped correctly on my side.
